# Access a jQuery object stored in .data() from parent document (outside an iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm looking for a way to get a value (CodeMirror-instance) which is stored using jQuery's `.data()`-method from outside the `document`-context it was stored from.

My case is I have a jQuery-dialog with a CodeMirror-instance. I'm trying to create an ajax-save function but when the converted textarea is submitted, CodeMirror provides a callbackfunction which puts the current content to the textarea again.

I need the stored instance of CodeMirror from `.data()` to perform the callback manual so I can start processing the contents. Can this be achieved? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my problem using an AJAX-save solution, therefore I didn't need to access the object anymore.